# Correct syntax for multiple product ID's for Google Ads in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I'm using Google Tag Manager to pull in some data for my Google Ads. When I goto a product page, I've just hard coded some product ID's as an example, but I get the following error:

[image]

This is how I've defined the product ID's, it's saying multiple ID's need to be in an array, to my understanding they are.

Where am I going wrong?
[image]

Comment: You don't need to quote the product IDs, since they are numbers

Comment: @aynber I've tried without the quotes and the same error appears, I just can't work out why it's getting flagged. I have the ID's as a GTM variable too, was using `{{order-items}}` which outputs `193, 194, 195` but no luck with that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use your GTM variables `{{order-items}}` (that contains in your case *193, 194, 195*) in a **Custom Javascript Variable** to generate an array from your comma-separated string, like this:

```
function() {
  var products = {{order-items}};
  return products.split(",");
}
```